# How to use storm's New Metrics Reporting API?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I use the storm V1.2.1. After setting up according to the official documentation, I want to get some metrics in the spout, the spout code is as follows, but there is no expected metric data in graphite-web.

**Question 1**：How to use the New Metrics Reporting API correctly？

**Question 2**：How do I get the ACK number metric in the storm-bound KafkaSpout by using Storm's Old or New Metrics API?

Using New API in the spout to get the number of the tuple：

```
      public static class MyTestWordSpout extends BaseRichSpout {
            public static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestWordSpout.class);
            boolean _isDistributed;
            SpoutOutputCollector _collector;
            private Counter tupleCounter;
            transient CountMetric ackcountMetric;
            long msid=0;


            public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
                _collector = collector;
                this.tupleCounter = context.registerCounter("tupleCount");
                ackcountMetric = new CountMetric();
                context.registerMetric("ack_count", ackcountMetric, 5);
            }

            public void close() {

            }

            public void nextTuple() {
                Utils.sleep(100);
                final String[] words = new String[] {"nathan", "mike", "jackson", "golda", "bertels"};
                final Random rand = new Random();
                final String word = words[rand.nextInt(words.length)];
                _collector.emit(new Values(word),msid++);
                this.tupleCounter.inc();

            }

            public void ack(Object msgId) {
                  ackcountMetric.incr();
            }

            public void fail(Object msgId) {

            }

            public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
                declarer.declare(new Fields("word"));
            }
        }
```

storm.yaml：

```
storm.metrics.reporters:
  # Graphite Reporter
  - class: "org.apache.storm.metrics2.reporters.GraphiteStormReporter"
    daemons:
        - "supervisor"
        - "nimbus"
        - "worker"
    report.period: 1
    report.period.units: "SECONDS"
    graphite.host: "10.11.6.79"
    graphite.port: 2003
  - class: "org.apache.storm.metrics2.reporters.ConsoleStormReporter"
    daemons:
        - "worker"
    report.period: 1
    report.period.units: "SECONDS"
```

graphite browser:
[graphite browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDZfu.png)

Comment: I am also seeking for this information. If you have solved it could you please share here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library https://github.com/staslev/storm-metrics-reporter. Add this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.staslev</groupId>
  <artifactId>storm-metrics-reporter</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Add this configuration to your topology:

```
config.put(YammerFacadeMetric.FACADE_METRIC_TIME_BUCKET_IN_SEC, 30);
        config.put(SimpleGraphiteStormMetricProcessor.GRAPHITE_HOST, "127.0.0.1");
        config.put(SimpleGraphiteStormMetricProcessor.GRAPHITE_PORT, 2003);
        config.put(SimpleGraphiteStormMetricProcessor.REPORT_PERIOD_IN_SEC, 10);
        config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_NAME, YOUR-TOPOLOGY.class.getCanonicalName());
        config.registerMetricsConsumer(MetricReporter.class,
                new MetricReporterConfig(".*", SimpleGraphiteStormMetricProcessor.class.getCanonicalName()), 1);
```

And add the following call into the `prepare` method of your bolts:

```
public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
        StormYammerMetricsAdapter.configure(stormConf, context, new MetricsRegistry());
```

Then you can see at your browser if Graphite shows the metrics.
[image]

Comment: But this is unfortunately not the new metrics system (under `org.apache.storm.metrics2`).